# Change between Stages in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I was working on making a simple user login window (I will be using the word 'window' to make reference to 'Stage') that would close the current window and open another one that has the content of the app. This app will have an exit button that should return to the user login window. Below is the code I currently have (showing only the part that cause conflict).

This is what I have in the Main class.

```
//boton 1
   Button signIn = new Button();
   signIn.setText("Sign In");
   signIn.setOnAction(e -> {
       if("agus".equals(usernameBox.getText()) && "12345".equals(password.getText()))
       {
           //I use instances of both classes and send the window as parameter to switch 
           //between windows
           appWindow app = new appWindow();
           app.start(window);
       }
   });
   signIn.setLayoutX(130);
   signIn.setLayoutY(350);

   window.setScene(scene);
   window.setMaxWidth(350);
   window.setMaxHeight(500);
   window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> window.close());
   window.show();
```

This is the code in the content Class.

```
//Button Exit
    Button exit = new Button();
    exit.setText("Exit");
    exit.setOnAction(e ->{
       App2 login = new App2();
       login.start(window);

    });

    window.setTitle("Game Stage");
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.setMinWidth(800);
    window.setMinHeight(550);
    window.show();
```

When executing, the app seems to work, but when returning to the login window, the size of the window keeps the size defined in the content class. Why does this happen? Is there a better practice way of implementing this? I've seen examples using FXML, in this case I'd like to use JavaFX only.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--

Comment: Well that was a simple fix. Thank you.